# How can I make my Python vowel counter count all of the vowels at once, rather than individually?

Tags: python

I'm rather new to Python. I've coded this vowel counter:

```py
str = "aeiou"
vowels = 0
for i in str:
  if (i=="a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"):
     vowels = vowels+1
print("The number of vowels is:")
print(vowels)
```

but it's returning this:

```
The number of vowels is:
1
The number of vowels is:
2
The number of vowels is:
3
The number of vowels is:
4
The number of vowels is:
5
```

How can I get it to count all of the vowels at once and just provide the total (i.e. 5 in this case)

Comment: `if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u":` OR `if  i in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):`OR `if  i in "aeiou":`

Comment: ```if i in str.split('')``` should do

Comment: probably you have wrong indentions and you use `print()` inside `for`-loop but you should use it after `for`-loop

Comment: Indentation problem. Keep the print() statement outside of for loop.